# Converting rectangular grids to an array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm using `ndgrid` to create a series of rectangular grids.  For example :

```
nx = [1 2 3];
ny = [4 5 6];
nz = [7 8 9];

[x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh] = ndgrid(nx, ny, nz);
```

Is there a simple way to convert the coordinates of the rectangular grids to a NxM array (in this case 27x3)?  The result should look like this:

```
[1,4,7;
 1,4,8;
 1,4,9;
 1,5,7;
 1,5,8;
 1,5,9;
 1,6,7;
 1,6,8;
 1,6,9;
 ...
 3,6,7;
 3,6,8;
 3,6,9]
```

If possible, I'd like to specify the direction in to compile the coordinates in the array.  For example, the above moves along z, then y, then x.  It'd be nice if one could specify to move in the order x, then y, then z instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code gives you the array you describe.

```
nx = [1 2 3];
ny = [4 5 6];
nz = [7 8 9];

[x_mesh, y_mesh, z_mesh] = ndgrid(nx, ny, nz);

grid = reshape(permute([x_mesh; y_mesh; z_mesh],[3 2 1]),[],3);
```

To iterate on x first, then y, then z you can just use

```
grid = [x_mesh(:) y_mesh(:) z_mesh(:)]
```

A generic solution which gives you more direct control over the order of iteration is

```
order = [1 3 2];
grid = reshape(permute(cat(4,x_mesh,y_mesh,z_mesh),[order 4]),[],3)
```

Which iterates on x first, then z, then y.

Comment: I was just about to come back and comment on the ordering but then saw you updated the answer.  This works beautifully!  Great solution!

Comment: probably worthy of another question, but if one had a series of values in an array, and knew the order, what would be the mechanism to put those array values into a mesh?  Or in other words, go the do this inverse when `nx`, `ny`, and `nz` are not consistent.

Comment: I would have to think about the generic solution but if you used the x-y-z order (second expression) then you can just do `x_mesh = reshape(grid(:,1),[numel(nx), numel(ny), numel(nz)]);` and similarly for `y_mesh` and `z_mesh` using columns 2 and 3 from `grid`. If you don't know `nx`, `ny`, and `nz`, you can get them (possibly out of order) using `nx = unique(grid(:,1)); ny = unique(grid(:,2)); nz = unique(grid(:,3));`

Comment: ah yes duh ... that makes sense

Comment: in my application going from `grid` to `x_mesh`, `y_mesh`, and `z_mesh` it isn't that I don't know `nx`, `ny`, `nz`, but rather the grid in this case represents the dependent variable, so they just aren't applicable.